# Display JCheckBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a Jtable in which I want to add a JCheckbox in one column. However, when I create a JCheckbox object, javax.swing.JCheckBox is being displayed in the column.Please refer to the image. Can you tell me how to amend that please? I have searched everywhere but cannot seem to find any solution for it. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. don't add components to your `TableModel`, that's not the responsibility of the `TableModel`
2. You will need to specify the class type of your column.  Assuming you're using a `DefaultTableModel`, you can simply fill the column with a bunch of booleans and this should work - After testing, you will need to override the `getColumnClass` method of the `DefaultTableModel` (or what ever `TableModel` implementation) and make sure that for the "check box" column, it returns `Boolean.class`

See [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestCardLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCardLayout();
    }

    public TestCardLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Random rnd = new Random();
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Check boxes"}, 0) {

                    @Override
                    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                        return Boolean.class;
                    }

                };
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{rnd.nextBoolean()});
                }
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not using any table model just the default one. I have used vectors to construct the table. I have also tried Booleans but true and false are being displayed, not the JCheckBox. Thanks

Comment: 1- You are using a `TableModel`, it just happens to be called `DefaultTableModel`, which has a method called `getColumnClass` which you need to override in order to return the expected class type for each column and make sure, for the check box column, you return `Boolean.class`, as the example demonstrates, then all the magic happens for you

Comment: Do you need a new DefaultTableModel for each column? How would you scale this to hold the whole table?

Comment: @bmc No, you only need one TableModel