# Sorted JTable's return value of rowAtPoint(Point)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to make a Checkbox change value on click in a JTable. Here is the code I use for that in the MouseListener

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point mouse = e.getPoint();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(mouse);
    int col = table.columnAtPoint(mouse);
    if (col == 0) tableModel.setValueAt(new Boolean(!(Boolean) tableModel.getValueAt(row, col)), row, col);
}
```

The problem is, that when I sort the table, this happens

[image: Problem with sorting]

Here is an SSCCE

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SSCCE extends JFrame {

    JTable table;

    public SSCCE() {
        setSize(300, 200);
        Object[][] data = { {false, "This is false"}, {true, "This is true"}};
        table = new JTable(new CustomTableModel(data));
        add(table);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        Object[][] data;

        public CustomTableModel(Object[][] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return data[0][columnIndex].getClass();
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return data[0].length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SSCCE();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this? Or a better method (not ListListener) to detect clicks on cells?

Comment: Find the solution at [How to add checkboxes to JTABLE swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391877/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-jtable-swing) that's working fine in your case as well. You don't need to add mouse listener at all.

Comment: I would guess your problem is that you haven't implemented the `setValueAt(...)` method in your custom model so the editor can't save the updated value. There is no reason to create a custom TableModel. You can just use the `DefaultTableModel` and override the `getColumnClass(...)` method.

Comment: Don't use [data[0][columnIndex].getClass()] to determine the column type! what happens if the value is null? When sorted, you need to translate between the view and the model indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a MouseListener. You just need to use a proper editor for the column and the table will handle it for you.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Basically you need to do two things:

1. Add `Boolean` data to the `TableModel`
2. Override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the `TableModel` to return `Boolean.class` for that column and the table will choose the appropriate editor.

Above is the answer for your question, but for future information the MouseEvent is relative to the table, so you want to use table methods to access the data. That is you would use `table.getValueAt(...)` and `table.setValueAt(...)`. These reference the data as it is currently displayed in the view of the table. That is the view could be sorted or the column could have been moved.

Comment: I could only make use of the last part. When I do the 2 things you mentioned, it only makes the checkbox and doesn't update it when I click it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Check my updated answer for an SSCCE and please show me the correct way to do it.

Comment: @usama8800 You could take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822376/display-jcheckbox-in-jtable/23822410#23822410), while I've not tested the edibility, the basic concept should get you started